# Can 'it' refer to a plural noun?

Tags: usage

I think ***it*** refers to ***all the tasks that AI-powered by artificial intelligence can do***. But is it possible for ***it*** to refer to the plural noun, ***all the tasks***? If so, ***all the tasks*** must be used as a single concept.

> You may have seen headlines in the news about some of the things
> machines powered by artificial intelligence can do. However, if you
> were to consider all the tasks that AI-powered machines could actually
> perform, ***it*** would be quite mind-boggling!

[How Rapidly Is Artificial Intelligence Technology Growing?](https://whatiscomputer.in/how-rapidly-is-artificial-intelligence-technology-growing/)

Answer (score 3):

Here, *it* refers to the hypothetical event of your considering “all the tasks AI-powered machines could actually perform.”